# Babel can't recognize ... in syntax. (Redux)

Tags: reactjs, webpack, redux, babeljs, webpack-2

Babel can't convert the ... in my Redux reducer. I keep getting an error message when running Webpack with Babel:

```
ERROR in ./src/reducers/api_reducer.js
Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token (18:15)

  16 |   switch(action.type) {
  17 |     case FETCH_MESSAGE:
> 18 |       return { ...state, message: action.payload };
     |                ^
  19 |     case FETCH_EVENTS:
  20 |       return { ...state, eventList: action.payload };
  21 |     case CREATE_EVENT:
```

These are my installed dependencies:

```
 "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.17.0",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.1.4",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.16.0",
    "css-loader": "^0.26.1",
    "file-loader": "^1.1.4",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.30.1",
    "image-webpack-loader": "^3.4.2",
    "rimraf": "^2.6.2",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.1",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.9",
    "webpack": "2.2.0-rc.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.2.0-rc.0"
  }
```

and my .babelrc goes like that:

```
{
  "presets": ["babel-preset-env", "react"]
}
```

Could anyone tell me why the ... can't get transpiled? How did you solve this issue? -Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Object rest/spread is a stage 3 proposal at the moment, so it's not included in `babel-preset-env`. You can either:

- include only this specific transform with `.babelrc`:

  {
    "plugins": ["transform-object-rest-spread"]
  }
- include all stage 3 proposals with :

  {
    "presets": ["env", "react", "stage-3"]
  }

Comment: @str I mean, while in poor taste, it's hard to say that this answer isn't more complete than your's or CD's...

Comment: @Aymeric Bouzy aybbyk I entered what you told me to and now I get a new kind of syntax error. Do you know what might cause this one? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46532922/syntaxerror-in-webpack-react-js-unexpected-token-in-react

Comment: @str : I started writing my answer and saw yours only when i published. Because I felt mine was more complete, I didn't remove it.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`transform-object-rest-spread`](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-object-rest-spread/) babel's plugin.

> Transform rest properties for object destructuring assignment and spread properties for object literals

Answer (score 2):

You are using the [object spread operator](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-object-rest-spread) which is currently a stage-3 feature. They are not supported by babel-preset-env. You need to add [babel-preset-stage-3](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-stage-3/).