# SyntaxError in Webpack / React.js Unexpected token = { } in React

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs, jsx, webpack-2

In one of my .js file, I'm getting the following error from Webpack:

```
  4 | export default function(ComposedComponent) {
  5 |   class Authentication extends Component {
> 6 |     static contextTypes = {
    |                         ^
  7 |       router: React.PropTypes.object
  8 |     }
  9 |
```

These are my devdependencies:

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.17.0",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.16.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-3": "^6.24.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.26.1",
    "file-loader": "^1.1.4",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.30.1",
    "image-webpack-loader": "^3.4.2",
    "rimraf": "^2.6.2",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.1",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.9",
    "webpack": "2.2.0-rc.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.2.0-rc.0"
  }
```

And this is my Webpack configuration:

```
{
  "presets": ["env", "react", "stage-3"],
  "plugins": ["transform-object-rest-spread"]
}
```

Could anybody tell which plugin or package is missing?
Thank you!

Comment: Please look at [this](https://github.com/babel/babelify/issues/167) and [this](http://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-class-properties/). You just need to add correct babel presets to be able to use static class properties.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing is missing, it's just incorrect syntax.

Static methods should be (as the name implies) functions.

Try:

```
class Authentication extends Component {
   ...
}

Authentication.contextTypes = {
    router: React.PropTypes.object
}
```

Comment: Same issue... Now, it's pointing to the . between the Authentication.contextTypes. Interestingly, it was OK with the old setup when I downloaded the tutorial, it's just not working with my new Webpack transpiler.

Comment: Longshot but try `babel-preset-es2015` and add `es2015` to your presets

Comment: @Daniel is right. You just have to add correct presets. Look at my comment for links.

Comment: Thank you for your efforts, but I just keep getting error messages. This time is Uncaught Error: _registerComponent(...): Target container is not a DOM element - even thought the script is at the documents bottom. :(

Answer (score 1):

Class properties is a stage 2 proposal at the moment, so it's not included in `babel-preset-env`. You can either:

- include only this specific transform with `.babelrc`:

  {
    "plugins": ["transform-class-properties"]
  }
- include all stage 2 proposals with :

  {
    "presets": ["env", "react", "stage-2"]
  }

Please consider the risks before adding all `stage-2` proposals : https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-stage-2/